# converting Div to Canvas options

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I convert an HTML element to a canvas element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732488/how-can-i-convert-an-html-element-to-a-canvas-element)

I know it is pretty simple to convert an image into a canvas, but how do I convert a DIV to a canvas?  I'm hoping to avoid a huge script like http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Comment: Out of curiosity, why on earth do you want this functionality?

Comment: perhaps duplicate but no good answers.  I am trying to save some text on the image, I already did in php, but would prefer a js solution.

Comment: What's wrong with using `ctx.drawText` for that purpose?

Comment: Nothing, I will have to code this up myself and use ctx.drawText but I will have to add a lot of code to make sure embedded fonts, colors, paddings, and everything else gets rendered correctly.  I was hoping someone has already done some of this work