# Opacity gradient transition of div

Tags: javascript, css, gradient, opacity

So.... I have some div elements, and I want to fade them, on a mouse click of another element, into complete transparency.  But I don't want to fade them all at once.  I want to fade them left to right, in a gradient, starting at full opacity and ending in full transparency.

I don't have any code because I couldn't find anything on the web that talked about this.

I appreciate any help anyone would want to provide.

Comment: Are you trying to do something like [diagonalFade](http://jonobr1.github.com/diagonalFade/) or do you need something that can fade the left side of a single div while the right side is less faded?

Comment: The latter is exactly what I would like to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can create fadeIn function and fadeOut function with jQuery and call itself in the call back within the same function until all the elements have been processed:

http://jsfiddle.net/UukNh/1/

```
allDivs = $(".container div").length; // get number of elements

$(".button").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('fadeIn')
    if ($(this).hasClass('fadeIn')){
        fadeOut(0); // function to hide elements
    }else{
        fadeIn(0); // function to show elements
    }
}     



var fadeOut = function(i) {  
    $("div.container div:eq("+i+")").fadeTo('slow', 0, function() {
        if(i <= allDivs ){
           fadeOut(i+1);   
        }
    })
}

var fadeIn = function(i) {
    $("div.container div:eq("+i+")").fadeTo('slow', 1, function() {
        if(i <= allDivs ){
           fadeIn(i+1);   
        }
    })
}


// This just changes the text of the button.

$('.button').toggle(function() {
    $(this).text('Fade in');
}, function() {
    $(this).text('Fade Out');
});
```

Comment: Thank you; however, I would still want to make it a gradient in a single div.  If this is not possible, then that would be something I would like to know, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Clone your div into (n) number of instance you want, each cloned div have (a) width and place next to each other

```
Original
                                                Clones
-----------------             --------------------
|               |             |   |   |   |   |   |
|               |     =>      |   |   |   |   |   |
|               |             |   |   |   |   |   |
|               |             |   |   |   |   |   |
-----------------             --------------------
```

Now you can run a loop to fade from left to right

(This technique is use in nivo slider)

There is an edge js library http://www.netzgesta.de/edge/. What happen if you animate the edge? Can you try

Comment: Thank you, but is there no way to make gradient of opacity in a single div?

Comment: I don't think so :( Can you try to create an transparent overlay png and then add on top of the div?

Comment: There is an edge js library http://www.netzgesta.de/edge/. What happen if you animate the edge? Can you try

Comment: Overlaying a png would be static, though, and I want a transition - animation of watching the div element (singular) become transparent from the left to right - so while the left side is a little transparent, the right is still opaque, but eventually the whole thing becomes transparent.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YfHN6/3/).

Here's the JS:

```
var fadeDivs = $('.fadeDiv'),
    fadeDiv = (function () {
        var maxDivs = fadeDivs.length,
            i = -1;
        return function () {
            i += 1;
            if (i === maxDivs) return;
            $(fadeDivs[i]).animate({opacity: '0'}, 500, fadeDiv);
        };  
    })();;

fadeDivs[0].onclick = fadeDiv;
```

`fadeDiv` gets called each time the previous `div` finishes animating.

Comment: Thank you, really, but see comment on above answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to:

1. Place a transparent HTML5 canvas over top of the div
2. Render the div in the HTML5 canvas
3. Hide the div
4. Use [alpha transparency](http://jakearchibald.com/scratch/alphavid/) to create the transparent gradient effect

First you'd have to figure out the solution to [rendering an HTML5 element in an HTML5 canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732488/how-can-i-convert-an-html-element-to-a-canvas-element).

If your div is just an image or something simple you still might be able to take this approach by rendering each component of the div in the canvas yourself