# aspx to jpeg image conversion

Tags: c#, asp.net

Am trying to convert aspx page to image i.e save it as a png file. I used iecapt for this. I have many textboxes on aspx page. The problem is the textbox values are not saved in the image file. Am just getting the source file image. Hope i get some suggestions on this.
Thank You

protected void btnsend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        string url = "http://localhost:4101/WebForm3.aspx"; 

        if(Request.Params["weburl"] != null)
        {     
            url = Request.Params["weburl"];      
        }               
        string savepath = String.Format("C:\\IECapt\\{0}.png" , System.Guid.NewGuid());    
        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();   
        process.StartInfo.FileName  = "C:\\IECapt\\IECapt.exe";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("\"{0}\" \"{1}\"",url,savepath);
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;  
        process.Start();    
        process.WaitForExit();  
        process.Dispose();  
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "image/png";
        Response.WriteFile(savepath);
        Response.End(); 
    }
```

Comment: You try the same as this one, but with images http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12342519/how-to-play-sound-by-clicking-button-in-asp-net

Answer (score 1):

```
The problem is the textbox values are not saved in the image file.
```

Of course they not, if they do then every one it will be able to read out entered data - but also this is not the case, the case is **that the page that you load did not contains any entered data - is one isolate load**.

When you do that you thing that you load what user see, but actually not, you not see what user see, you just make one more load of the page.

**You must distinguish between the code that run on server and the code that run on client browser.**

You ask also the same at: [Screenshot of webpage in asp.net c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12541780/screenshot-of-webpage-in-asp-net-c-sharp)

Comment: ok..i got it.. but is there any way to save aspx page as an image along with textbox values? Coz i need to send that image file via email and the recepient must be able to download it and print.

Comment: @user1665707 I have told you that on the previous answer. Look at that examples: http://experiments.hertzen.com/jsfeedback/  Click the button on the bottom right

Comment: Thanx for the suggestion but am not able to download htmltocanvas as its blocked. So was trying other approaches. Can i send a div as body of the email. My div has all controls.

Comment: @user1665707 I do not understand what you talking about. Is not blocked at all, I just download it. https://github.com/niklasvh/feedback.js   There is not other approaches, and you are lucky that this lib exist :)