# Can I draw a table in canvas element?

Tags: jquery, html, image-processing, html5-canvas

Is there any way (plugins, working solutions, etc.) to draw a `HTML` `table` into a `<canvas>` element?

I have a rich-formatted html table (using `CSS`), and I want to save it as image (PNG, SVG or GIF) using `jQuery`. ...or if there any simpliest way, I'm listening it.

Comment: I don't think you can access the pixel data of rendered HTML elements with JS (without using any browser plugin)

Comment: You should check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6789627/1102014) and after it created a screenshot on canvas, you can get picture by calling `canvas.toDataURL();`.

Comment: Yep, I'm trying to parse how it works :) Possibly you have some working example?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/YZMhk/2/)

Sure, it is possible. You can draw DOM objects into a canvas. Here is the code you need:

```
<p><canvas id="canvas" style="border:2px solid black;" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var data = "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='200' height='200'>" +
             "<foreignObject width='100%' height='100%'>" +
               "<div xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' style='font-size:40px'>" +
                  "<table border='1'><tr><td>row 1, cell 1</td><td>row 1, cell 2</td></tr><tr><td>row 2, cell 1</td><td>row 2, cell 2</td></tr></table>" +
               "</div>" +
             "</foreignObject>" +
           "</svg>";

var DOMURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self;
var img = new Image();
var svg = new Blob([data], {type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"});
var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);
img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
};
img.src = url;
</script>​
```

[You can find more information here on Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas#Example)

Comment: This is great! Thank you! I'm new for SVG. Can you help me how can I use my `CSS` file for this generated `SVG` image?

Comment: Not sure if you can use external css styles. Check out the link for more information that I supplied in this answer.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but there should be a note about the fact that this will taint the canvas in all browsers except Edge and Firefox, thus making all programmatic exports unavailable.

Comment: Your provided link is no longer available!

Comment: @autopilot - an alternate [link](https://reference.codeproject.com/book/dom/canvas_api/drawing_dom_objects_into_a_canvas)