# THREE.JS : Width limit with text in sprite material

Tags: three.js

I get an issue with text inside sprite materials. I use this code : https://github.com/stemkoski/stemkoski.github.com/blob/master/Three.js/Sprite-Text-Labels.html

It works but if text is too long, text is truncated :

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0qN1.png)

I tried to increase canvas width but text become too small, I can't understand why.

Comment: I think what you need to do is set the size of the canvas `canvas.width = textWidth;canvas.height = textHeight;`. Have a look at the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44026172/show-table-in-sprite-using-three-js)

Comment: Yes this code works perfectly tank a lot