# Append DOM element to the D3

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js

I'm using D3 for drawing on the SVG. What I want is to append DOM element or HTML to the D3, like:

```
task.append(function(model){
//here return html or dom
};
```

Documentation says it's possible, but unfortunately I can't find any example or found out how to do this myself.

Comment: Need more clarity! Do you wish to add HTML elements to your canvas? What are `task` & `model`? Should you not consider removing the `svg` tag?

Comment: Yes, I need to add some HTML to the canvas. Task is d3 selection.

Comment: To be more clear I need to append HTML to the d3 selection using it's append method. https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-append

Comment: If you wish to draw DOM elements onto a canvas then [here's the link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTML/Canvas/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas) on how to do it. 

But if you wish to *append* HTML elements to canvas then I'm afraid to say [that can't be done](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732488/how-can-i-convert-an-html-element-to-a-canvas-element).

Comment: Are you using `<canvas>` or `<svg>` for your graph??? Most d3 uses `<svg>`, and I'm afraid @srvikram13 is just confusing you in that case.  To add an HTML element within SVG, you have to first add a [`<foreignObject>` tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/extend.html#ForeignObjectElement), then add the HTML element within it.  However, be warned that browser support is somewhat buggy.  Depending on what you're doing, you might consider drawing the HTML element on top of the SVG but not a child of it.  Look up tooltip examples for how to position it.

Comment: @AmeliaBR Miss, the question has been edited to replace 'canvas' with 'svg'. In which case, my response was apt, and not confusing.

Comment: @srvikram13 yes, sorry for the implied snub -- I checked the edit log after leaving my comment.

Comment: Yes, sorry. That was my fault - I wrote canvas, but meant SVG. I found a solution for my problem. I'll update the answer later.

Comment: @JackSpektor can you post the update for the solution, I'm struggling with something similar

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The selection.append() function accepts one of two types:

- A **string** which is the name of an element to create, or
- A **function** which is executed (applied on parent) and should return an element or HTML.

Your question wasn't very specific, so I'll do a wild guess here.

## Appending custom created elements to a d3 selection

If you created your element using

```
var newElem = document.createElement(tagname);
```

or

```
var newElem = document.createElementNS(d3.ns.prefix.svg, tagname);
```

and you want to add that new element to your d3 selection then you can use this:

```
mySelection.node().appendChild(newElem)
```

This will basically append the new element to the **first** node from your selection. For appending the element to every node from the selection you'd need to make a loop over mySelection and call node() on every single item.

Adding multiple custom created elements works the same, but you can save yourself some work using `element.cloneNode(true)`

Note however that you can't use any of d3's magic on plain elements, except you wrap them in `d3.select(elem)`.

## Appending a d3 selection to a d3 selection

Let's assume you have two selections **s1** and **s2** and you want s2 to be appended to s1. If both are selections over only one element respectively, then you can simply use

```
s1.node().appendChild(s2.node())
```

or

```
s1.append(function() {return s2.node()})
```

If s1 and/or s2 are being selections over multiple elements you need to iterate over both selections first and use

```
s1[i].node().append(s2[j].node())
```

or

```
s1.append(function() {return s2[i].node()})
```

instead.

Comment: Or with function:  `s1.append(function() { return s2.node() });`

Comment: Thanks @roland, added your suggestion to the answer.

Answer (score 22):

Try this:

```
d3.select("body").append(function() { return document.createElement("p") });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how used this information to create dynamic "shapes" in my force-directed chart using a function inside append().

```
shape = svg.append("g")
  .selectAll("rect") // only a placeholder - does not control the shape
  .data(force.nodes())
  .enter()
  .append(function(d){
   return setshvape(d)
    })


function setshape(d){
   if(d.type == "start"){
     var shape = document.createElementNS(d3.ns.prefix.svg, "circle");
   }else{
    var shape = document.createElementNS(d3.ns.prefix.svg, "rect");
    }
return shape
}
```