# How can I append my own SVG object in D3?

Tags: javascript, object, d3.js, svg, graphics

I can easily append a **circle** object using [D3.js](https://d3js.org/http://) as follow :

```
var bodySelection = d3.select("body");
var svgSelection = bodySelection.append("svg")
                            .attr("width", 50)
                            .attr("height", 50);

var circleSelection = svgSelection.append("circle")
                            .attr("cx", 25)
                            .attr("cy", 25)
                            .attr("r", 25)
                            .style("fill", "purple");
```

My question is, is it possible to append my own svg object and how ?

The result should look a little something like this:

```
var bodySelection = d3.select("body");
var svgSelection = bodySelection.append("svg")
                            .attr("width", 50)
                            .attr("height", 50);

var myObjSelection = svgSelection.append("MyObject")
                            .attr("MyObjectAttribute1", 25)
                            .attr("MyObjectAttribute2", 25)
```

Comment: You can find the idea here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21727202/append-dom-element-to-the-d3

Comment: sure but your own object won't do anything.

Comment: My own object would be for example a specific shape with functionnalities related to it

Comment: there's no such thing in SVG, only the elements in the spec are renderable (circle, ellipse, path etc), anything else won't display.

Comment: can't I create my specific shape with a path element and add function to it?

Comment: Yeah. But you have to use `.append('path')`.

Comment: what about the document.registerElement function could this work?

Comment: @JSmith SVG will only render the elements in the spec, as Robert Longson already told you.

Comment: ok thank you then :).