# how to generate DST file in magento

Tags: magento

i am currently working on custom product preview extension in which customer is able to add graphics and text to product on product view page (view.phtml) , let us take example i am buying a tshirt and i want to customize it so i will add some graphics design along with some text and then place order . What i want is i want to generate a dst file on successfull order placement so that admin can be able to see the order along with customize product more clearly with the help of DST file. how to generate this DST file ??

Answer (score 0):

Well you can create image by using Canvas.
I hope few reference links mentioned below will help you.

a) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas
b) [How can I convert an HTML element to a canvas element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732488/how-can-i-convert-an-html-element-to-a-canvas-element)