# Allowing users to take 'screenshot' of parts of webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to allow users to capture screenshots of targetted elements (paragraphs) of my
webpage and then displaying the captured screenshot on a div (not canvas) where they can download the screenshot.

Here is a visual of what I'm trying to accomplish: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vuar6.png

This is what I've ***tried*** so far:

**HTML**

```
    <p id="content">lorem ipsum bla blah, screenshot me like one of your French girls</p>
<h1>Right click image in div below and download:</h1>
    <div id="display" width="500" height="200"></div>
    <button>capture</button>
```

**JS**

```
 document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
     (document.querySelector("#content")
        });
    };
```

**CSS**

```
#display {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        button {
            clear: both;
            display: block;
        }
        #content {
            background: rgba(100, 255, 255, 0.5);
            padding: 50px 10px;
        }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://html2canvas.hertzen.com

Comment: These could help: [Capture HTML Canvas as gif/jpg/png/pdf?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923885/capture-html-canvas-as-gif-jpg-png-pdf) -- [How can I convert an HTML element to a canvas element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732488/how-can-i-convert-an-html-element-to-a-canvas-element)

Answer (score 0):

This is much more complicated than you might imagine(especially if you’re planning to take “screenshots” of arbitrary content). Fortunately, there’s a JS library that does this!

http://html2canvas.hertzen.com

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a way to "screenshot" an elemement. I think that you will have to use a canvas element and then save the canvas content as a picture.
Read more about it here:

[How to take screenshot of a div with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887183/how-to-take-screen-shot-of-a-div-with-javascript)